# Divisibility of determinants and matrix rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have stumbled upon an exercise that is giving me nighmares. I've found that it is quite common in older exercise books, but I haven't even heard about it in class or seen it in any lecture in all my years in college, even if it seems to be a basic and simple problem. Naturally, as it happens, these promblem books don't have a solution for it (They just skip it in the solution pages). Here it is:

> Given the matrix A=$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a_{11} & a_{12} & ... &  a_{1n} \\
> a_{21} & a_{22} & ... &  a_{2n} \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \\
> a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... &  a_{nn} \end{array} \right) 
> \in M_{n}(N) / (a_{11}, ..., a_{1n})$ are single-digit natural positive numbers, prove that the determinant of the matrix A is divisible by the GCD of the numbers formed by the rows of the matrix.

I have tried applying determinant proprieties, solving the actual determinant and juggling with everything I know, but I just have no idea about how to do this. It is very unlikely that they ask us something like this at all, but I am very cusious and I want to know how can this be explained.

Edit: Since this is confusing to write, here is another exercise I found using this:

> The numbers 20604, 53227, 25755, 20927 and 78421 are all divisible by 17. Prove that the determinant $\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
> 2&0&6&0&4 \\
> 5&3&2&2&7 \\
> 2&5&7&5&5 \\
> 2&0&9&2&7 \\
> 7&8&4&2&1 \end{array} \right|.$ is also divisible by 17

It's the same concept and it can be seen more clearly.

Comment: What is $M_n(N)/(a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n})$? A quotient of some kind?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe I typed something wrong there, it means that the matrix is a square matrix formed by naturals in which every element of the matrix is a single-digit positive natural number.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. You are not saying that $\det\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$ is divisible by $12$ and $34$? Please clarify.

Comment: I second @HenningMakholm's comment. That notation must indicate something else. What book are you getting this from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, it says that the GCD of the numbers formed with the rows (12 and 34 in Andrea's comment) can divide the determinant, which is what I meant (I edited the question since it was confusing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the desired proof, for a $3\times 3$ matrix for simplicity.

1. Add $10$ times the second column to the third column.  This doesn't change the determinant.
2. Add $100$ times the first column to the third column.  This too doesn't change the determinant.  Now the third column contains values that are the rows of the original matrix.
3. The gcd of those original rows divides each element of the last column of the matrix; hence by taking the Laplace expansion on that column, that gcd must divide the determinant.

Comment: Now everything seems extremely obvious, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be claiming that the matrix 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose determinant is $-5$, has a determinant that is divisible by both the number $14$ and the number $23$. Or maybe the notation $a_{i1} \ldots a_{in}$ means a product, in which case it's claiming that the determinant is divisible by both $4$ and $6$. In either case, both are false.

Comment: Now the question is about $\gcd(14,23)=1$.

Comment: Ah...that makes sense, now that the problem's been edited. I might have been able to answer that one, although not nearly as cleanly as you did. :)